# How to implement correct work of generator without changing entry function?

Tags: javascript

From some component, I will send a string with a specific name and will return some set of data  (if this name in object key). If object property contains an array with few objects with the same structure but different values, I want to send on every call next object.

But when I try to do that I got the same value every time:

```
{ value: { a: 1 }, done: false }
{ value: { a: 1 }, done: false }
{ value: { a: 1 }, done: false }
```

instead of:

```
{ value: { a: 1 }, done: false }
{ value: { a: 2 }, done: false }
{ value: { a: 3 }, done: true}
```

**So how to get the expected result which I described above without changing this part of code:** (and names of the object "mocks" properties  (foo, bar, baz))

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  foo.Query('c');
}
```

All code which you can run and see the result

```js
const test = {
  a: { id: 1 },
  b: { id: 2 },
  c: [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { c: 3 }]
};

function* generLoop(elem) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef,no-restricted-syntax
  for (el of test[elem]) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    yield el;
  }
}

function createLoop(elem) {
  let gen;
  if (elem === 'c') {
    gen = generLoop(elem);
  }
  console.log(gen.next());
  return () => (gen ? gen.next() : test[elem]);
}

const iterators = {};

const mocks= {
  Query: elem => ({
    foo: test.a,
    bar: test.b,
    baz: createLoop(elem)
  })
};

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  mocks.Query('c');
}
```

Comment: Every time you call `foo.Query()` you're creating a new iterator that starts from the beginning.

Comment: What is the code with `foo:` `bar:` and `baz:` supposed to do? It's not creating an object (those are statement labels, not object keys), and even if it did, it's doesn't do anything with the object. Did you mean `return { foo: ... }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Query` so that, when an item is queried, it looks up the current iterator for that item, if it exists (and creates a new iterator if not). Then log the result of calling the iterator inside of `Query` (not inside of `createLoop`, whose job it is to just create the iterator):

```js
const test = {
  a: {
    id: 1
  },
  b: {
    id: 2
  },
  c: [{
    a: 1
  }, {
    a: 2
  }, {
    c: 3
  }]
};

function* generLoop(elem) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef,no-restricted-syntax
  for (el of test[elem]) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    yield el;
  }
}

let gen;

function createLoop(elem) {
  if (elem === 'c') {
    gen = generLoop(elem);
  }
  return () => (gen ? gen.next() : test[elem]);
}
const iterators = {};
const foo = {
  Query: elem => {
    iterators[elem] = iterators[elem] || createLoop(elem);
    console.log(iterators[elem]());
  }
};

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  foo.Query('c');
}
```

Or, if the iterator-caching functionality has to be done in the strangely-named `createLoop` function (said function would be more properly named `iterateLoop` or something, since the implementation requires it to only *iterate*, but not necessarily *create* the iterator each time it's called):

```js
const test = {
  a: {
    id: 1
  },
  b: {
    id: 2
  },
  c: [{
    a: 1
  }, {
    a: 2
  }, {
    c: 3
  }]
};

function* generLoop(elem) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef,no-restricted-syntax
  for (el of test[elem]) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    yield el;
  }
}

let gen;

function createLoop(elem) {
  if (!gen) {
    gen = generLoop(elem);
  }
  return gen.next();
}
const mocks= {
  Query: elem => ({
    foo: test.a,
    bar: test.b,
    baz: createLoop(elem)
  })
};

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log(mocks.Query('c').baz);
}
```

Comment: Also, we can't change object "mocks" properties  (foo, bar, baz) , because that will change expected behaviour. I updated my question please have a look

Comment: See edit, but that's kind of strange. A function named `createLoop` should *create* a loop, but the implementation you require has it *iterate*, but not necessarily create a loop

Comment: cool, but in case, if we got not an iterable object like property "b" from test object,  we get an error. So condition on !gen isn't correctly

Comment: Then just check if the property on the object is iterable or not first